# Possible to use multithreading in sqlite3 without application interface?

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 from the command line in Ubuntu to do some transformations on my data and I'm noticing that many of my larger commands are not pushing the CPU above ~30% utilization, and disk IO is a lot lower than I know its capable of.

I've seen lots of documentation on using sqlite multithreading with various APIs and programming languages, but is it possible to simply use more threads to accomplish my single task from the sqlite cli?  Unfortunately I can't go on to the next transformation until the previous has completed or I would simply connect another session and do that.

Comment: Have you tried simply running the commands in the background using job control in bash (or whatever shell you use)? e.g. ( ./run1; ./run2 ) &;

Comment: Thanks @CharlieDalsass but I'm not really following you.  I'm trying to use multiple threads on a single data intensive command like an INNER JOIN or a CREATE AS or something.  How would I use jobs to accomplish that?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_threads

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand your question better now. @CL may be on to something... it seems you can adjust the number of threads internally used by sqlite3 using that pragma. Let us know if that improves performance of your queries.

Comment: THANK YOU @CL. I guess I should have been searching for 'threads' instead of 'multithreading'.  I knew this had to be possible.  You should add your comment as an answer so you can get those sweet sweet internet points!

Comment: So I'm running a CREATE INDEX command right now and even though I set `PRAGMA threads = 8;` it's only using 1 thread according to `ps -o nlwp <pid>`.  Seems to be going about the same speed

Comment: What does `PRAGMA threads` return? It's possible that `sqlite3` was compiled without threads.

Comment: It returns 8, and I even did `PRAGMA threads;` just to make sure that it also returned 8.  I used the sqlite3 from the Ubuntu 16 repos, I may need to compile it for myself with multithreading, I'll check on what the repos have.

Comment: Yea looks like its turned off by default in linux precompiled binaries https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=MultiThreading

Comment: Also just saw this, looks like there's a reason the Ubuntu repo had it off by default.  They pretty strongly discourage multithreading https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q6